# How can I make this kind of concave Ngons?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, topology

Just recently I received a file containing a 3D model extruded from a .dxf 2D file.

I'm trying to replicate that 3d model from the original .dxf file.

[image: animation 1]

I notice that the 3D model has [this kind of polygons](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1saSPPkFPhLKVqgIFSDULqtrYQ15HHiTO/view?usp=sharing) (concave Ngon), not squares, but a square intervened by another square with no additional diagonal edges.

[image: animation 2]

When I try to create faces\polygons from the 2D file, I get [this kind of topology](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1heKur5kFTjIa28SDwrOTchkieyEiDsW2/view?usp=sharing) where the face overlaps everything and creates a single square polygon.

How Can I make it behave like the first one above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my own testing of a similar shape, it appears this result will happen if your edges are not properly joined. Typically imported geometry can suffer from 'loose' geometry.

When they are joined, blender correctly figures out the surface.

Simply select all and run a "Merge by Distance" operator and you should be able to fill the face correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I knew it has to be a really simple solution. Cheers!!